# Controller is null when autowired

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a controller named ReportController which accesses data from repository successfully. I autowired the class in another class where I handle WebSocket messages, as I will like to send websocket messages to and fro the database as well. The problem is however, when I autowire the controller class in the SocketHandler class and call methods from there, it gives a null pointer exception.  I have annotated the controller with @Component or @Service without success. My classes are below

```
package com.labafrique.creporter;

import com.labafrique.creporter.property.FileStorageProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        FileStorageProperties.class
})
@SpringBootApplication

public class CreporterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CreporterApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Controller class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.labafrique.creporter.controller;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.labafrique.creporter.model.ReportModel;
import com.labafrique.creporter.repository.ReportRepository;
import com.labafrique.creporter.service.FileStorageService;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

/**
 *
 * @author Javalove
 */

@Service
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/creporter/listener")
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    private ReportRepository caseRepo;

    @Autowired
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;



    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportController.class);


    @GetMapping(path="/getCases")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCases(@RequestParam("t") String type, @RequestParam("x") String x)
    {
        return URLDecoder.decode(new Gson().toJson(caseRepo.findByCaseType(type, Integer.parseInt(x))));
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/getSent")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSent(@RequestParam("sender") String sender, @RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("phone") String phone, @RequestParam("type") String type)
    {
        try
        {
            email = URLEncoder.encode(email, "utf-8");
            sender = URLEncoder.encode(sender, "utf-8");
            phone = URLEncoder.encode(phone, "utf-8");
            type = URLEncoder.encode(type, "utf-8");
        }catch(Exception er){}
        return URLDecoder.decode(new Gson().toJson(caseRepo.getSent(sender, email, phone, type)));
    }


    @PostMapping(path="/add")
    @ResponseBody
    public String save(@RequestParam("code") String code, @RequestParam("category") String category, 
            @RequestParam("details") String details, 
            @RequestParam("audio") String audio, 
            @RequestParam("video") String video,
            @RequestParam("photo") String photo, 
            @RequestParam("address") String address, @RequestParam("rtype") String rtype, 
            @RequestParam("caseLocation") String caseLocation, 
            @RequestParam("userLocation") String userLocation,
            @RequestParam("photoFile") MultipartFile photoFile, 
            @RequestParam("videoFile") MultipartFile videoFile, 
            @RequestParam ("audioFile") MultipartFile audioFile,
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("phone") String phone,
            @RequestParam("sender") String sender,
            @RequestParam("thumb") String thumb)

    {
        String uploadingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/CReporterUploads/";
        System.out.println(uploadingDir);
        String result = "error";
        ReportModel model = new ReportModel();
        model.setAddress(address);
        model.setCaseLocation(caseLocation); 
        model.setCategory(category);
        model.setCode(code);
        model.setAudio(audio);
        model.setVideo(video);
        model.setPhoto(photo);
        model.setDetails(details);
        model.setRtype(rtype);
        model.setEmail(email);
        model.setSender(sender);
        model.setPhone(phone);
        model.setThumb(Integer.parseInt(thumb));
        model.setUserLocation(userLocation);
        if(audio.equals("true") )
        {
            doUpload(uploadingDir, audioFile, code);
        }
        if(video.equals("true") )
        {
            doUpload(uploadingDir, videoFile, code);
        }
        if(photo.equals("true") )
        {
            doUpload(uploadingDir, photoFile, code);
        }
        ReportModel md = caseRepo.save(model);
        /*
        if(attachment != null && attachment.length > 0)
        {
            logger.info("i'm in bro");
            uploadM(attachment, code);
        }
        */


        return new Gson().toJson(model);


    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/thmbUp")
    public void vote(@RequestParam("code") String code)
    {
        caseRepo.ThumbUp(code);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/welcome")
    public String getPage()
    {
        return "mapping";
    }




    public boolean doUpload(String uploadingDir, MultipartFile uploadedFile, String code)
    {
        System.out.println("about to upload photo");
        boolean done = false;
        File f = new File(uploadingDir +code + "/");
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
        try
        {
            File file = new File(uploadingDir + "/"+code + "/" +uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
            uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
        }
        catch(IOException er)
        {
            er.printStackTrace();
        }
        return done;
    }


    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public String test()
    {
        try{
        String uploadingDir1 = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/creporter/";
        Path path = Paths.get(uploadingDir1);

        if (!Files.exists(path)) {

            Files.createDirectory(path);
            return("Directory created");
        } else {

            return("Directory already exists");
        }
        }catch(Exception er){return er.getMessage();}
    }




    @GetMapping("/getFile/{fileName:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Load file as Resource
        String a[] = fileName.split("_");
        Resource resource = fileStorageService.loadFileAsResource(a[1], a[0]);

        // Try to determine file's content type
        String contentType = null;
        try {
            contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info("Could not determine file type.");
        }

        // Fallback to the default content type if type could not be determined
        if(contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
    }




}
```

And my socket handler class

```
package com.labafrique.creporter.controller;

import com.labafrique.creporter.controller.ReportController;
import com.labafrique.creporter.repository.ReportRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler  {


        @Autowired
        ReportController report;




    List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            {
        //Map<String, String> value = new Gson().fromJson(message.getPayload(), Map.class);
        /*for(WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
            webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello " + value.get("name") + " !"));
        }*/
            //session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello " + value.get("name") + " !"));
                            try
                            {
                        System.out.println(message.getPayload());
                        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("i received "+message));
                String t[] = message.getPayload().split("##");
                //try {session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(control.test())); }
                //catch(Exception ee){session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(ee.getMessage()));}
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("alldata##"+report.getCases("cor", "0")));
                if(message.getPayload().startsWith("AllData"))
                {
                    //System.out.println(control.("cor", "0"));
                    //session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("alldata##"+report.findByCaseType("cor", Integer.parseInt(t[1]))));
                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception er)
                            {
                                er.printStackTrace();
                            }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        //the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("welcomeBro##xx"));
                //session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("alldata##"+report.findByCaseType("cor", 0)));
                //session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(control.test()));
        sessions.add(session);
    }

        public void sendLatest(String latest)
        {
            for(WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) 
            {
                try
                {
                webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage("latest##"+latest));
                }catch(Exception er)
                {}
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: First of all that's a bad idea to autowire Controller. Very likely you have some structural problems in your application if you want to do that. Please try to explain why you need controller Injection into another class.

Try to move all functionality you need in Controller and other service into another bean which you autowire into your controller and SocketHandler .

Comment: thanks Alex... I needed the injection because I want to be able to access the save(), getSent() and getCases() methods. From your explaination, am I supposed to create a seperate class to perform the tasks?

Comment: Yes. You need to move all common methods into separate bean class.

Comment: could you kindly Alex show me an example Bean class to achieve this? I created a bean controller class but it wont allow me annotate with @Bean. Thanks in advance

Comment: In fact if you annotate a class with `@Service` or `@Component` annotation Spring framework create an instance of this class as a bean and you can `@Autowire` it in another bean classes. `@Bean` annotation is also used for beans creation but in different way.

Comment: thanks Alex for helping out. The challene still remains... SocketHandler class is not recognising any class annotated with either Component or Service...

Comment: I think my problem has to do with calling that bean from the sockethandler class because I tried a creating new classes and calling the methods....It works successfully.....I am confused now

Answer (score 2):

Wow...after almost a week of debugging, I found the problem....In my Websocketconfig class, I created a new instance of SocketHandler which was what caused the problems... so I changed my config class to

```
@Autowired
SocketHandler handler;

public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(handler, "/socket");
}
```

Intially, I had **new SocketHandler()** within the register method. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this.

```
@Service
public class ServiceBean {

    public String getCases(String type, String x)
    {
        return URLDecoder.decode(new Gson().toJson(caseRepo.findByCaseType(type, Integer.parseInt(x))));
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/creporter/listener")
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    private ReportRepository caseRepo;

    @Autowired
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceBean serviceBean;

    @GetMapping(path="/getCases")

    @ResponseBody
    public String getCases(@RequestParam("t") String type, @RequestParam("x") String x)
    {
        return serviceBean.getCase(type, x);
    }
}

@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler  {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceBean serviceBean;

    // do here anything you want with methods of serviceBean
}
```